# CSS Elemento "passando" sobre o outro numa li

Tags: html, css, css3

Tenho um select (dropbox) personalizado, no qual há um campo de busca na lista, esse select com jquery foi baixado (não fui eu que fiz), pois bem, eu tive que posicionar um sobre o outro para minha finalidade, o problema é que um select sobrepõe o outro quando ativo, como se fosse transparente, já alterei no css a propriedade position, z-index, background color e nada, vou deixar um print do problema, alguém sugere algo? não tenho muita intimidade com frontend (css)

primeira imagem com o primeiro select selecionado (sem nenhum por baixo)
segunda imagem com um select a cima de outros, olhem como fica a list do options

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui],
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

abaixo o trecho do css:

```
/* @group Results */
.chosen-container .chosen-results {
  color: #444; 
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  max-height: 240px;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
.chosen-container .chosen-results li {
  display:none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 1px 1px;
  list-style: none;
  text-align:left;
  z-index: 999999 !important
}
.chosen-container .chosen-results li.active-result {
  display: list-item;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.chosen-container .chosen-results li.disabled-result {
  display: list-item;
  color: #ccc;
  cursor: default;
}
.chosen-container .chosen-results li.highlighted {
  background-color: #3875d7;
  color: #fff;
}
.chosen-container .chosen-results li.no-results {
  color: #777;
  display: list-item;
  background: #f4f4f4;
}
.chosen-container .chosen-results li.group-result {
  display: list-item;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: default;
}
.chosen-container .chosen-results li.group-option {
  padding-left: 15px;
}
.chosen-container .chosen-results li em {
  font-style: normal;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

/* @end */
```

Comment: Põe um `z-index: 999999 !important` no _css_ do _select_ e testa.

Comment: Obrigado a todos que responderam, o select não é o problema, e sim a lista com as options, esse jquery gera um li em css com os resultados, e essa lista não sobrepõe o select que está abaixo, como nas fotos.

Comment: Qual é o plugin que você está usando para fazer isso?

Comment: @DouglasFernandes, uso o plugin Chosen

https://plugins.jquery.com/chosen/
https://davidwalsh.name/demo/jquery-chosen.php

Comment: Galera consigo baixando novamente o css do plugin, mas até agora não sei qual era o problema. obrigado a todos